# AWS Cloudfront with W3TC not pulling all static files

Tags: wordpress, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a WordPress website hosted on AWS EC2 instance.

I have set up Cloudfront as my CDN and connected it with W3TC plugin.

I have set W3TC to origin pull. Most of my content is being sent to Cloudfront (as identified by the URL)

Example:

```
http://d5ilgn0jt451p.cloudfront.net/wp-content/ ... LayerSlider/static/css/layerslider.css?ver=5.6.9
```

However, there are a number of images that don't get sent to Cloudfront.

I have checked my pagespeed with GTMetrix and it identifies 26 static images as (shown below) that are not sent via the CDN.

Is there a way to push these static images to the CDN?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have your Wordpress site on EC2 you don't really need to use W3TC. You could pass all your site through Cloudfront. Check this out: [enter link description here](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront)